# How do I apply css code for svg in google api charts

Tags: css, google-maps, svg

I want to apply some css code for the selected item in the image below:
[image]

How can I do that? I tried smth like that:

```
text[name="text-anchor"] {display:none}
```

and also why I cannot do that ?:

```
    g g g text[text-anchor]{display:none} 
    g g g:first-of-type text[text-anchor] {display:block} 
    g g g:last-of-type text[text-anchor] {display:block}
```

smth like this

Comment: is there any way you can give a id or class to the text or svg element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just `text[attr]` for an attribute selector and > for child of...

```css
g > g > g > text[text-anchor] {display:none}
```

```html
<svg>
    <g><g>
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="30">now you see me</text>
      <g><text text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="50">now you don't</text>
    </g>
    </g></g>
</svg>
```

You could use g:first-child or g:first-of-type to get the first (text) child of a `<g>` element.

Comment: Will this not effect all text elements that have an text-anchor attribute?

Comment: but is there a way that can I display only the first and the last element ?  As you can see the <text> is in a <g>. And  i want to display the first and last <g>.

Comment: g text[text-anchor]{display:none}
g:first-of-type text[text-anchor] {display:block}
g:last-of-type text[text-anchor] {display:block}   smth like this ?

Comment: you can do something like that yes.